# Why call() function stopped working in solidity 0.5.0?

Tags: solidity, remix

I am sending ether to another smart contract and calling its fallback function with higher gas as like:

```
contractAddress.call.value(1 ether).gas(53000)();
```

It was working in solidity version 0.4.25 but it stopped working in 0.5.0 giving me error:

> TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 0 arguments given
>   but expected 1. This function requires a single bytes argument. Use ""
>   as argument to provide empty calldata.

If I try to add blank argument in call() as it says in the error, then it gives me another error:

> TypeError: Member "value" not found or not visible after
>   argument-dependent lookup in tuple(bool,bytes memory) - did you forget
>   the "payable" modifier?

I studied the [breaking change documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html) but that still could not find the solution.
Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure `contractAddress` is of type `address payable`. And yes, you'll need to provide an argument. E.g.:

```
address payable contractAddress = ...;
contractAddress.call.value(1 ether).gas(53000)("");
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks again sir.. The mistake I was making was, that I was doing:           `contractAddress.call("").value(1 ether).gas(53000)();` means adding ("") after call which is incorrect. And as you suggested, I did:  `contractAddress.call.value(1 ether).gas(53000)("");`  and that worked!

Comment: @smarx I am facing the same issue with the following code :  `require(msg.sender.call.value(rewardAmount).gas(36000)(""));`. How would you specify the type of msg.sender ? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whoever comes here and sees the accepted answer should know that the approach by itself contains potential errors for the contract logic and provides a gateway for attackers.

Whenever you use `call` you should check the return value of the function called. It will return false if it reverts.

```
(bool success ,) = cA.call.value(1 ether).gas(xx)("");
```

Furthermore It's suggested to only do this with trusted addresses. Any contract can easily implement logic to do reentry attacks. If you want to do it with non-trusted addresses, add a `mutex` flag to any of your other functions.

Something like this:

```
contract XX {
    bool mutexFlag;

    function untrustedCall(address payable _untrusted) public {
        require(mutexFlag == false, "No reentry!");
        // do stuff
        mutexFlag = true; // set mutex
        (bool success, ) = _untrusted.call.value(xxx)(""); // transfer funds without breaking things
        mutexFlag = false;
        require(success, "Transfer failed!");

        // do some more stuff
    }
}
```